# How to use a machine learning model with Weka on Android to predict new values?

Tags: android, machine-learning, weka

I've been searching various links on how to get Weka running on Android to be able to use machine learning models to do predictions. The most promising answer I've seen is this: https://github.com/andrecamara/weka-android which lets me add Weka to my Android Studio project.

But what do I do from here? Once I've added it, how can I actually use it to predict values? And if I have a model trained already (using Weka 3.9.2), can I use that model to do the predictions?

Answer (score 1):

andrecamara uses an old Weka version, 3.4.3 to be exact. You can verify this in weka.core.version class. In short, you can't use https://github.com/andrecamara/weka-android to load a model from Weka 3.9.2. You will face the following error message.

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: weka.classifiers.trees.RandomTree; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -9051119597407396024, local class serialVersionUID = 8934314652175299374
```

For the second part of your question, there are 2 options.

1. Use an archived version of Weka to generate the model again, or
2. Look at https://github.com/ohmrefresh/Weka-Android-3.9.1-SNAPSHOT. 
   Its one revision off but it might work.